# UIView Animation Freezes

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, message, uikeyboard

I'm implementing drag-keyboard dismissal (like in the iPhone Messages app) manually because [`UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive` doesn't seem to work with a text view inside a toolbar above the keyboard](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl/commit/d6def98f2cd7db55675d6951ded8392e3f021399).

It works in portraint mode, but in landscape orientation, sometimes when I animate the toolbar (which is actually just a `UIView`) & keyboard, they freeze. But, they did animate because I checked using breakpoints that the animation code ran and when I tap on the screen where they're supposed to be, I get the correct reactions (like keyboard keys pop up, etc.).

I'm using the old style of animations `beginAnimations:context:` because this is [how to mimic the keyboard animation in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837166/how-to-mimic-keyboard-animation-on-ios-7-to-add-done-button-to-numeric-keyboar/18876428#comment28963700_18876428).

This seems like an iOS SDK bug. How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps its getting cancelled.
Also, you can mimic the keyboard animation using more modern style (ie animation blocks). Also you may want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930423/uitextview-keyboarddismissmode-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sometimes (when the pan velocity was large) using `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear` instead of the curve from the keyboard notification's `userInfo`. I took that condition out so that I always use the curve from the keyboard notification's `userInfo` and things seem to be working fine now.