# react-native `keyboardShouldPersistPanGesture` event that prevents the keyboard from dismissing on fast swipe events

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am building a keyboard accessory component where there will be a scroll through option above the keyboard, very similar to Twitter's keyboard. My view hiearchy is:

```
<InputAccessoryView>
    <View style={myStyle}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
           {[...Array(n).keys()].map(uid => this.renderBubble(uid) })}
        </ScrollView>
   </View>
</InputAccessoryView>
```

By putting `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` as `always`, I can make sure the press event does not dismiss the keyboard. However when I scroll through the items in `ScrollView`, the keyboard dismisses if I scroll *too quickly*, the keyboard does not dismiss if I scroll slowly. The docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system and here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onmomentumscrollbegin do not give me a way to capture a long pan event. Is there an API to do this so I scroll through the `ScrollView` items as fast as I want, and the keyboard will *not* dismiss?

Comment: A snack expo [link](https://snack.expo.io) to generate the issue would be helpful, thanks

Comment: maybe simple way just  create your own listener for scrolling and prevent native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check some of these sources:

https://geekhub.co.kr/react-native/releases/0.37/docs/scrollview.html

[Dismissing the keyboard in a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143873/dismissing-the-keyboard-in-a-uiscrollview)

https://medium.com/react-native-training/todays-react-native-tip-keyboard-issues-in-scrollview-8cfbeb92995b

https://geekhub.co.kr/react-native/releases/0.37/docs/scrollview.html

https://rebolt.callstack.com/docs/scroll-view.html

[UITextView keyboardDismissMode Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930423/uitextview-keyboarddismissmode-bug)

hopefully this makes it easier for you. I know this isnt a solution that you may be looking for, but it will give you a starting point, i will continue working on this and if i find something will come back here and edit my answer.